# MethodInfo.Invoke with params argument

Tags: c#, reflection, invoke, parameters, methodinfo

I have a static class `HelperMethods` that contains static methods. I need to dynamically invoke a method in an assembly where the `HelperMethods` is contained, but this assembly is just sometimes available. So I can't have a reference on that assembly containing the method I need. Also I can't copy the code of this method, since it generates a custom object `SpecificServiceHost` derived from `ServiceHost` that I need, but the other part of code just needs to know that it is a `ServiceHost` object. In case `SpecificServiceHost` is not available the method simply creats a regular `ServiceHost` object.

```
private ServiceHost TryFindSpecialServiceHost()
{
  try
  {
    var dynamicType = Type.GetType("Common, SuperApplication.Common.HelperMethods", true);
    // Should find "public static SpecificServiceHost CreateSpecificServiceHost(Type serviceType, params Uri[] baseAddresses)" method
    var createServiceHost = dynamicType.GetMethod("CreateSpecificServiceHost",
                                                  BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static,
                                                  null,
                                                  new[] { typeof(Type), typeof(Uri[]) },
                                                  null);
    var dynamicInstance = createServiceHost.Invoke(null, new object[] { typeof(IMyWcfServiceContract), null });

    return (ServiceHost) dynamicInstance;
  }
  catch
  {
    return new ServiceHost(typeof(IMyWcfServiceContract));
  }
}
```

Now the `createServiceHost.Invoke` throws an exception that `baseAddresses` must not be `null` due to the implementation of `ServiceHost` in the framework. I thought that the `params` argument would allow `null` references. But it doesn't! What should I do? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry! I just found out myself... It is so stupid of me! :)

Simply change:

```
var dynamicInstance = createServiceHost.Invoke(null, new object[] { typeof(IMyWcfServiceContract), new Uri[0]});
```

To initialize with empty list of base addresses!